# Object containing an array going to nil

Tags: ruby, class

I have a class `Deck` that represents an array of 81 cards but when I try to use my getter functions on any card in the array it gives the error `undefined method getColor for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` which I assume means that everything in my array equals `nil`.

I am trying to figure out how to set up my `Deck` class so that I can return any card by just using the `getCard` function and then use the card getter methods to then obtain all values of the individual card.

```
class Card  
    def initialize id, symbol, color, shading, number
        @cardId = id #0-80 unique for each indivdual card in the deck
        @cardSymbol = symbol # 0 = diamond 1 = squigly 2 = oval
        @cardColor = color # 0 = green 1 = blue 2 = pink
        @cardShading = shading # 0 = none 1 = lines 2 = solid
        @cardNumber = number #number of the symbols on the card
    end

    def getId
        @cardId
    end

    def getSymbol
        @cardSymbol
    end

    def getColor
        @cardColor
    end

    def getShading
        @cardShading
    end

    def getNumber
        @cardNumber
    end

end

class Deck

    def initialize
        @deck = Array.new(81)
        @cardDealt = Array.new(81)
    end

    def AddCardsToDeck  
        cardId = 0
        symbol = 0
        color = 0
        shading = 0
        number = 0
        while cardId < 80
            if symbol > 2
                symbol = 0
                color = color + 1
            elsif color > 2
                color = 0
                shading = shading + 1
            elsif shading > 2
                shading = 0
                number = number + 1
            else
                symbol = symbol + 1
            end 
            card = Card.new(cardId, symbol, color, shading, number)
            cardId = cardId + 1
            @deck[cardId] = @card
        end 
    end

    def getCard cardId
        @deck[cardId]
    end
end

setDeck = Deck.new
setDeck.AddCardsToDeck
card0 = setDeck.getCard(0)
puts "Color is #{card0.getColor}"
```

Comment: `@deck[cardId] = card` plus `cardId += 1` should definitely be at the end of deck card assignment

Comment: As a note unrelated to the question, while your code will still run just fine, you may be interested in reading a style guide to learn how Ruby prefers to style code. [This guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) seems to be popular, in particular the [Naming](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming) describes how we like to name things. There's also an [`attr_*`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#attr_family) family of functions that you can use for trivial getters like in the `Card` class

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
card = Card.new(cardId, symbol, color, shading, number)
cardId = cardId + 1
@deck[cardId] = @card
```

are the problem. Note how the local variable `card` is set in the first line, while the uninitialized instance variable `@card` is used in the third. This sets all the entries to `nil`.

Another issue is incrementing the `cardId` before using it as an index. This will set card 0 into slot 1 etc. A classic "one off" error.

Comment: Ugh i kept thinking that it was an error with my class structure I overlooked this trivial problem. Thanks!